# URL is not opening in Safari browser from UIWebview delegate method

Tags: ios, uiwebview, xcode4.5

I am trying to load UIWebview from my class here is a testClass.h file of it

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface testClass : UIView<UIWebViewDelegate>

@property(nonatomic,retain) UIViewController *superObj;
- (void) showView;
@end
```

and below is code for testClass.m, superObj is a main viewContrller's self assigned from it.

```
@synthesize superObj; //assigned from viwController as self 
- (void)showView {
    CGRect firstRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100.0, 50.0);
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:firstRect];
    webView.delegate = self;
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/inapp/index.php"]]];
    [superObj.view addSubview:webView];
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSLog(@"In delegate method");
   if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] isEqual:@"http://localhost/inapp/index.php"])
        return YES;    
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];//opens url in safari
   return NO;
}
```

this is is able to show UIWebview and renders html in it, but when I click on url control is not going to shouldStartLoadWithRequest method. I am not able to understand why this is not working.

Comment: shouldStartLoadWithRequest runs only on URL change. check if your URL is changing.

Comment: my url is different in html page.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

**webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:**

Return Value
YES if the web view should begin loading content; otherwise, NO .